# Subscribe on events in tornado

Tags: python, asynchronous, web, callback, tornado

What is wrong with my event realisation?

```
class MyHandler(RequestHandler):
    counter = 0
    @coroutine
    def post(self):
        yield self.foo()
        self.write("Next 5 request!!!")

    @coroutine
    def foo(self):

        if MyHandler.counter == 0:
            MyHandler.callback = yield tornado.gen.Callback("MyEvent")

        MyHandler.counter += 1
        if MyHandler.counter == 5:
            MyHandler.callback()
            MyHandler.counter = 0
        else:
            tornado.gen.Wait("MyEvent")
```

I always have:

```
raise UnknownKeyError("key %r is not pending" % (key,))
UnknownKeyError: key 'MyEvent' is not pending
```

Also I found in tornado doc on Callback and Wait:

```
Deprecated since version 4.0: Use Futures instead.
```

But nowhere can find usecase of Futures for my situation.
Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that every request you get creates a new instance of `MyHandler`, so your `counter` and `callback` variables are not shared between requests. You really want them to be class variables, so that they're shared between the instances.

Here is how you can implement it with Futures:

```
class MyHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    fut = None
    counter = 0
    @coroutine
    def get(self):
        yield self.foo()
        self.write("Next 5 request!!!")

    @coroutine
    def foo(self):
        if MyHandler.counter == 0:
            MyHandler.fut = Future()

        MyHandler.counter += 1
        if MyHandler.counter == 5:
            MyHandler.counter = 0
            MyHandler.fut.set_result("done") # This will wake up waiting requests.
        else:
            yield MyHandler.fut
```

Comment: Exuse me, but I make a mistake in sample code. Counter and callback I store on application: self.application.counter. I checked - this part have not problem.

Comment: In your example with Future I have next problem. In first touch on yield MyHandler.fut ioloop has locked and on send request side I receive 599 http error for first 4 requests.

Comment: @SymonSoft Did you remember the `@coroutine` decorator? I can't reproduce the problem you're seeing on my system.

Comment: Yes. Both decorators on handler's post and foo().

Comment: I found the bug with lock of loop. Thank you @dano for use case of Future.